# How to run android studio first time when i'm offline?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have no internet connection. I want to use android studio but it gives me Gradle sync errors every time I try to use it.

Is there a way to run android studio without internet?

Note that I have SDK and JDK running well.

[image: Cant resolve jUnit error]

My java codes are not resolved too.
[image: Java methods error]

Comment: have  you downloaded SDK ?

Comment: Goto File->project structure->app->dependencies->click (-) button for JUNIT(its one of the temporary solution)

Comment: Wow. is it been two weeks that im tearing my hairs off for a (-) ?

Comment: That solved all the problems. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the latest gradle file from [here](https://services.gradle.org/distributions). Then in your Android Studio goto File->Settings->Build,Execution,...->Build Tools->Gradle. Then In the right side Check the "Use local gradle distribution" and then set the downloaded file as your gradle home. Below, in the Global gradle settings check the Offline Work option.->Click Ok.
DONE

**But Even though doing this will let you create a simple android app, you won't be able to import any external libs.**

Answer (score 3):

For Android Studio 2.3.0.8 (2/Mar/2017):

1. Goto File->Settings->Build->Gradle, check "Use local gradle distribution" and change "Gradle home" to: `[android-studio-path]\gradle\gradle-3.2` ***or whatever version there***, and check "Offline Work" option there.
2. Degrade the targeted gradle version of the project\build.gradle (not the app\build.gradle) like that (it was 2.3.0):

   `dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
       }`
3. Goto File->Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies, remove all but:

   `{include=[*.jar], dir=libs}
    com.android.support.appcompat-v7:23.3.0
    com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7`
4. Sync.

---

- **Be aware that the tricky IDE disables "Offline Work" option without notification, so you need to:**
- **Firewall those or it will download without notification:**

`[android-studio-path]\jre\bin\java.exe
 [android-studio-path]\bin\studio64.exe|studio.exe`

Comment: Unfortunately google disabled this solution in Android Studio 2.3.1 (4/4/2017), so I'm going to stick with 2.3.0.8, nice eye.. goo. keep watching.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to add local dependencies for JUnit with jar files

https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Download-and-Install

Download both files and copy them to your app/libs directory

And modify your build.gradle file as follow:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```