# how to build my android studio project in another machine with no internet?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, offline

I have to present my android-studio project to my employer in another machine which is NOT connected to internet.

My buildToolsVersion is "23.0.3" and my project also has some dependencies (third-party libs) via Gradle.

Is there a way to build my project in offline mode "in my own machine", and Run it in Employer's machine without Error such as SDK is not update OR failed to resolve: 'gradle-dependency-name'?

There are solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086993/how-to-run-android-studio-first-time-when-im-offline) but again it points out that it works just for simple apps.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171524/how-to-configure-gradle-to-work-offline-using-cached-dependencies) solution also said that gradle will work offline if it contains needed dependancies but .gradle folder on my employer's machine does not contain my dependencies for sure.

Comment: There is a new [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42743043) in one of the links you mentioned, check it out.

Comment: @captain_majid: thanx Cap